# show and hide elements using mysql enum and javascript in php?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am trying to simply show and hide an element depending on the value of an ENUM in mysql database.

I am using the javascript and PHP but it seems like the javascript within PHP does not or cannot select element given as the element is always on display!

here is my php code:

```
if ($sizeSelect != '1') {

echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
echo 'document.getElementById("sizeSelect").style.display = "block"';
echo '</script>';
}else{
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
echo 'document.getElementById("sizeSelect").style.display = "none"';
echo '</script>';
}
```

and this is my HTML element:

```
<select id="sizeSelect" name="sizeSelect">
            <option>Small</option>
            <option>Large</option>
            </select>
```

is there anything that I'm missing?

any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

P.S. I have made sure that I am connected to mysql database and get the ENUM value properly so the mysql connection is not an issue here.

okay, I just did a test within my html file and placed the following code at the top of the page and still didn't work but when I put the same code at the bottom of the page, it did work and changed the element's display to none:

```
 <script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
document.getElementById('sizeSelect').style.display = 'none';
</script>
```

SO, i did try this code in my PHP file with document ready function but still doesn't work from php file!

```
if ($sizeSelect = 1) {

echo "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>";
echo
"$(document).ready(function(){ document.getElementById('sizeSelect').style.display = 'block';});";
echo "</script>";
}else{
echo "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>";
echo "document.getElementById('sizeSelect').style.display = 'none';";
echo "</script>";
}
```

any help would be great.

Comment: Show us your **ENUM** structure and the way you're retrieving the **ENUM** field?

Comment: @FaresM. as I said, the issue is not from my enum! I get it echo-ed correctly on the page. BUT, i just did a test and it seems like the javascript doesn't even work on my page!!!!! strange..

Comment: The problem is with the _DOM_ and the order of your _javascript_ and **select** tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put your **php** code that generating the **javascript** after your **SELECT** tag or at the end of file, because your **javascript** doesn't find the DOM element **"#sizeSelect"**, i made test and it worked for me. like this:

```
<select id="sizeSelect" name="sizeSelect">
    <option>Small</option>
    <option>Large</option>
</select>

<?php 

    $sizeSelect = // retrieve sizeSelect value from your database;
    if ($sizeSelect != '1') {

        echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
        echo 'document.getElementById("sizeSelect").style.display = "block"';
        echo '</script>';
    }else{
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
        echo 'document.getElementById("sizeSelect").style.display = "none"';
        echo '</script>';
    }
?>
```

After you specified that you're using **Smarty**, i come back with a solution for that:

1. Concatenate your **js** content produced in php file on a string variable instead of using **echo**, and assign its value with **Smarty** `assign()` function

   ```
    $jsContent= '';
    if ($sizeSelect != '1') {
        $jsContent.= '<script type="text/javascript">';
        $jsContent.=  'document.getElementById("sizeSelect").style.display = "block"';
        $jsContent.=  '</script>';
    }
    else{
        $jsContent.=  '<script type="text/javascript">';
        $jsContent.=  'document.getElementById("sizeSelect").style.display = "none"';
        $jsContent.=  '</script>';
    }
    $smarty->assign('js', $jsContent);
   ```
2. Display the variable content as i said before, just after the **select** tag being targeted

   ```
    <select id="sizeSelect" name="sizeSelect">
        <option>Small</option>
        <option>Large</option>
    </select>
    {$js}
   ```

Comment: Yes, but I am using a template based PHP so the php file is separate from the HTML part. and I cannot put the php code in the html file.

Comment: Can you tell me how this PHP template gets included in your HTML?

Comment: its the other way round to be honest. the html template gets included in the php file. i am using smarty.

Comment: Okay, can i see your template or a part of it?

Comment: @user3592614 I updated my answer with a _Smarty_ based solution, take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have a div in which select will work, use Div for hide and show, see below

Code for HTML:

```
<div id ="sizeSelect">
<select id="select_id" name="select_id">
            <option>Small</option>
            <option>Large</option>
            </select>

</div>
```

and for php

```
if ($sizeSelect) {
 echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
 echo 'document.getElementById("sizeSelect").style.display = "none"';
 echo '</script>';
}else{
 echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
 echo 'document.getElementById("sizeSelect").style.display = "block"';
 echo '</script>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
if ($sizeSelect != 1) {
echo '<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">';
echo
'$( document ).ready(function() { $( "#sizeSelect" ).hide();});';
echo "</script>";
}else{
echo "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>";
echo
"$( document ).ready(function() { $( '#sizeSelect' ).show();});";
echo "</script>";
```

this is jQuery by the way.